# Why does the same date have different hours?

Tags: javascript, date

Maybe the answer is obvious, but I don't get it. Why are the Dates in the Code Snippet different? Does the format say something about the hours as well?

```js
console.log("2017-1-9 -->")
console.log(new Date("2017-1-9"))
console.log("2017-1-09 -->")
console.log(new Date("2017-1-09"))
console.log("2017-01-9 -->")
console.log(new Date("2017-01-9"))
console.log("2017-01-09 -->")
console.log(new Date("2017-01-09"))
console.log("2017-01-11 -->")
console.log(new Date("2017-01-11"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Even in my chrome-console and the code-snippet-console I get different dates:

[image]

My problem is not that both consoles log different dates. Look only at the `hours` in each console, for the very same date, only the `datestring` is different. Consequently my question:

**Why are the dates different?**

### UPDATE

Why is `new Date("2017-1-1").getTime() != new Date("2017-01-01").getTime() --> true`?

```js
var date = new Date("2017-2-9");
var dateWithZero = new Date("2017-02-09");
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getTime());
console.log(dateWithZero);
console.log(dateWithZero.getTime());
console.log(date.getTime() == dateWithZero.getTime());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: looks like you are in a UTC+1 time zone.  The date in the console is in UTC

Comment: In the Chrome-Console all Dates saying "GMT+0100", just the format of the "datestring" is different.

Comment: I get `null` for the first three dates in Safari…

Comment: Looks to be just down to the implementation of the `console.log` redirection feature in stack snippets.  The browser is logging one view of the object, stack snippets is logging just the zulu (UTC) time.

Comment: [parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @PaulAbbott In this instance, it's the _exact same object_ being presented in two different ways.  The browser is only parsing it once.

Comment: @DomeTune Your edit is a completely different question, but try `console.log(new Date("2017-1-1").getTime(), new Date("2017-01-01").getTime())`. You'll see why they aren't (necessarily) equal.

Comment: Yes but why? I know that they are not equal. I just dont know why the datestring format "yyyy-mm-dd" creates a different date than the datestring format "yyyy-m-d" for the same day?

Comment: "yyyy-m-d" is not a valid date format, so the browser throws away everything it doesn't understand. `new Date("2017-1-1")` is equivalent to `new Date("2017")`. This is very implementation-dependent, since the Date constructor isn't actually supposed to parse strings.

Comment: @Jordan Look at the new code Snippet. Its not because it takes `new Date("2017")`

Comment: You're passing `new Date` an invalid date string and expecting consistent results. You're not going to get them.

Comment: @Jordan thanks for your time, upvoted your answer, for the tip to not use datestrings for comparing. The Answer is that i am using an invalid dateformat "2017-2-9", because in some browsers, months or days with no leading zeroes may produce an error. If you add this to your answer i will mark it as right :-)

Comment: @DomeTune That wasn't my answer. ;) I've posted my own with excerpts from the spec, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Because the language specification says that date strings not conforming to the specified format can be parsed according to "any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats," and `YYYY-M-D` is just such a string.

Let's dive into the spec. Here's what the [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](https://es5.github.io/) says about the Date constructor (I'm quoting it instead of the current, ES2016 spec just because it's simpler, but the latter [works basically the same in this case](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date-value)):

> #### [15.9.3.2 new Date (value)](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.3.2)
>
> ...
>
> The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed
>   object is set as follows:
>
> 1. Let *v* be ToPrimitive(*value*).
> 2. If Type(*v*) is String, then
>
>    - Parse *v* as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the **`parse`** method ([15.9.4.2](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2)); let *V* be the time value for this date.
> 3. ...

And here's the spec for `parse` (emphasis mine):

> #### [15.9.4.2 Date.parse (string)](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2)
>
> The parse function applies the ToString operator to its argument and interprets the resulting String as a date and time... The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15)). **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.** ...

[Date Time String Format](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15), in a nutshell, is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` and its subsets. Since `YYYY-M-D` doesn't conform to that format, the interpreter is (unfortunately) free to do whatever it wants. If you want to know why Chrome does it in this particular way, you'll have to [dig around in the V8 source](https://github.com/v8/v8).

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

The dates being displayed are using different timezones.  The Chrome console output is using your browsers local timezone and adjusting it appropriately. The (GMT+0100) is telling you which timezone and adjustments that are being made.  The code snippet console is displaying using UTC.  The 'Z' at the end of the string signifies that.

If you want to convince yourself of that they are the same, print the timestamp for each date also.  This is also why when you are dealing with dates, you should rely on timestamps rather than comparing dates like this.  Things get very confusing and difficult to deal with.

Comment: I know that different browsers use different timezones. But how can `new Date("2017-1-1").getTime() != new Date("2017-01-01").getTime()`

Comment: Add `new Date("2017-1-1").getTime() != new Date("2017-01-01").getTime()` to you own console. It should be the same date, but it is not.

Comment: @DomeTune Your mistake is in assuming that two invocations of the same code will return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, months or days with no leading zeroes may produce an error:

```
new Date("2017-2-9");
```

In consquent, that the behavior of the format "yyyy-mm-dd" is undefined.

Some browsers will try to guess the format, some will return NaN and some will return null.

That is why `new Date("2017-02-09")` has `Thu Feb 09 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)` as output, because the behavior for this format is defined and it adds the timezone to the date. `new Date("2017-2-9")` has `Thu Feb 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)` as output, because chrome trys to guess the format, but cannot add the timezone. In Safari in return `null`.